# Sequence of functions in $L^p$ and derivative

Tags: derivatives, lebesgue-integral

if we have a sequence of functions,  $(f_n)_n \subset C^1(\mathbb{R})$ such that $f_n, f'_n \in L^p(\mathbb{R}) $ and $$f_n\rightarrow \phi_0 \, in \,L^p, $$
and $$f'_n\rightarrow \phi_1 \, in \,L^p.$$ Also, we can show that $(f_n)_n $ and $(f'_n)_n $ converge uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$. Can we conclude that $ \phi_0$ and $ \phi_1$ are in fact this uniform limits and in this case, $$ \phi_0 \in C^1(\mathbb{R})$$and $$\phi'_0=\phi_1.$$ Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yes. If a sequence of functions $g_n$ converges to $g$ in some reasonable sense and to $h$ in another reasonable sense then $g=h$. Here "reasonable sense" will include any common type of convergence. (Underlying this is the fact that any reasonable sense of convergence implies convergence in distribution and the distributional topology is hausdorff). Thus since $f_n$ converges to $\phi_0$ in $L^p$ and converges uniformly, it must converge to $\phi_0$ uniformly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but how can I prove this?

Comment: You can prove it for any subset of the reals, so maybe try proving it by unit-length intervals and doing explicit computations. (For example, if $\phi$ is the $L^p$ limit and $\psi$ the uniform limit, then try using $|\phi - \psi| \le |\phi - f_n| + |\psi - f_n|$ in combination with integration.)

Comment: But how can show that $|\phi(x)-f_n(x)|<||\phi-f_n||_{L^p}$ ?

Comment: Don't; just do the computations in $L^p$, using the $L^p$ triangle inequality.

Comment: Ok, I understand what do you mean, we obtain $$\int_K|\phi(x)-\psi(x)|^p=0, $$ i.e. $\phi(x)-\psi(x)=0, $ almost everywhere on $K$, but how can I pass to $\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Use the fact that any sequence that converges in $L^p$ has a subsequence that converges pointwise almost everywhere. Moreover, you know that the sequence $f_n$ in particular converges pointwise by converging uniformly.